# Time dependent workflow email alert is not received

Tags: workflow, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I have created a site to create case. I have a time dependent workflow in case object which will send email alert after one hour if the case is still at queue.

The Workflow action is triggered successfully and i can see it in Monitoring. but the user does not receive any email.

I have checked the email deliverable and i got 52 emails from salesforce.
I have added the same email alert in immediate workflow action and i got email.
This email alert has VF email template.

Can you help me on this? what could be the possibility of not getting email from sandbox?

Edit: I am using additional email address field only. I have tried with various email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

In a sandbox the user's email address is changed as part of the refresh process (see guidance [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&language=en_US)) do that would be why your user cannot receive the email. Update the address to be correct and retry.

Comment: I am using only additional email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You might also check email deliverability in the sandbox setup page.

Go to **Administration Setup > Email Administration > Deliverability** and then select Access level of **All Email**. If this was System email or No Access, then this would be blocking emails from workflow rules.

Comment: user2373234, consider also explaining why you feel this answers the question.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Sorry, I'm pretty new here and was in a rush when providing this answer. Is it better to give no reply than a short one?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you can still edit/update/improve it right now :-)

Comment: Thank you! After hours of searching, this finally worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from @pbattison, the diagnostic steps to look at would be

1. Examine Debug log to verify Email Alert is created (you did this)
2. Go to Monitoring | Email Logs and request an email log for the time period in question

The email log is very useful as it will document any errors in sending/receiving the email.  For example, you might find that email couldn't be delivered because the email address is incorrect (as suggested by @pbattison), or, more interestingly, as this happened to us two weeks ago, you get a DMARC error when dealing with yahoo.com domains. See this KB article: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193813

Lastly, email messages are never sent by testmethods (for obvious reasons - they would spam users)

Comment: I have checked the above, but i do not see anything wrong. finally i have created case with salesforce support. I will update once it is resolved. Thanks

Comment: So, the SFDC log says the email was received by the recipient's email system? If yes, then it could be a spam filter on the recipient's end