# Not receiving email from time-based workflows but shows in queue

Tags: workflow, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

I have a time-based workflow rule with 1 email alert and 3 field updates. Field updates are happening successfully but I am not receiving the email. I am using a VF email template. Email deliverability is also set to 'All email'.

I created a clone of the rule as an immediate rule and it works fine.

I also created a text based email template and replaced the VF template with this one in the time-based workflow rule and i received the email.

Below is the workflow rule.

[image: Workflow rule]

[image: Time-based actions]

**Email alert:**

[image: Email alert]

**Time based workflow queue:**

[image: Time based workflow queue]

Comment: @goodForce I see that you had posted the same question (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34846/time-dependent-workflow-email-alert-is-not-received?rq=1)  a few years ago. By any chance, do you remember the solution Salesforce might have provided? I could not ask you on your question as I don't have enough reputation points to be able to comment.

Comment: I have raised a Salesforce case and they are looking into it. In the meanwhile, since I am reaching my deadline, I am converting VF template to HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was in the template.

I had included slds css in the template.

```
<apex:slds/>
```

For some reason it was causing issues in time-based workflows but works fine in immediate ones. After removing it, I received the email.